# 'Special Price' comes up after the price update through MAGMI

Tags: magmi

After I update prices via `Magmi`, I get the old price displayed as a 'Special price' and the new price (from the update) as an 'old', crossed off price. I have tried with few different fields, all seems to be working perfectly fine (stock levels, some other settings) except for the price. When I edit the affected stock through `Magento 'manage stock'`, all setting are fine there, the price seems to be updated no problems, even that 'special price' field is blank (?), so I don't really know what is happening here... when I click 'save' it goes back to normal.

I have ~3,000 products, so updating the prices manually is not an option for me...
I have 2x shops if that matters.

Please help!
Thanks

Comment: What column headers are you using for the prices?  When you say "2x shops", do you mean you're running one instance of Magento with two websites?

Comment: At the beginning I tried with the following: 'store, websites, attribute_set, type, sku, price', then I limited to 'store, sku, price' only. Yes, it is one instance of magento with two stores (public and trade)

Comment: Forgot to mention that I have also tried with blank 'special_price', same results...

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Re-index prices in Magento backend. Then correct price changes will show.